# Automatically run a Linux executable with automatically updated Notepad++ file

Tags: linux, notepad++, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently working in WSL with a code that simulates something via an executable in the WSL window. To edit parameters (namely how long I want the simulation to run) for this executable I use Notepad++. I am currently interested in creating a moving gif for a couple of hundred of this simulation images, and obviously it goes without saying that it would be very time consuming to manually edit the Notepad++ code (time parameter, creating/naming a new directory for the simulation files to save in, etc) every time the executable has completed.

So I am wondering is there a method to automate this?
I suppose the method would have to go such as:

1. When the executable has finished, it automatically runs again with the updated Notepad++ file.
2. The Notepad++ file must then know WHAT parameters to update, how much to increase the time step, how to rename the new directory (maybe through some "++").

I am assuming there would be no way to really link these processes, and so maybe there would also need to be a time delay in when the Notepad++ file updates to allow enough time for the WSL executable to finish, and then undergo this process again?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this is going to require scripting/programming at some level.  Forgive me if I'm completely mistaken in this, but it does not sound like you have much programming experience.

At a high level, the script will probably:

- Operate in a `for` loop of some sort to repeat "x" number of times (you mention "a couple of hundred").
- Create a directory for the output
- Modify or create the configuration file for each run
- Run the simulation with that configuration file

I'm assuming that the parameters for each run will follow some sort of mathematical pattern that could be calculated based on the "number" of the run?  For instance, perhaps:

- One parameter increases by 3 for each run
- Another parameter only increases every 3rd run
- A final parameter cycles between 0,1,2 (mod 3)

Then your script might look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Starting values for first run
SIM_ARGX_START=1757
SIM_ARGY_START=8
for ((sim_num=0 ; sim_num < 200 ; sim_num++ ))
do
  mkdir "sim${sim_num}"
  SIM_ARGX=$(( $SIM_ARGX_START + ($sim_num * 3) ))
  SIM_ARGY=$(( $SIM_ARGY_START + ($sim_num / 3) ))
  SIM_ARGZ=$(( $sim_num % 3 ))
  cat << EOF > "sim${sim_num}/config"
[simparams]
ARGX=$SIM_ARGX
ARGY=$SIM_ARGY
ARGZ=$SIM_ARGZ
OUTPUT=sim${sim_num}/
other paramaters ...
EOF
  simprogram --config "sim${sim_num}/config"

done
```

That would write a hypothetical config file into 200 different directories named `sim0` to `sim199` and run the `simprogram` against it.

Of course, I have no idea of knowing what arguments or configuration file your particular simulation requires, so these are all hypotheticals.

The script or program can really be written in any programming language.  It's just that shell scripts are really good at automating things like this.  However, if you (a) don't have a programming background and (b) are running simulations (albeit unspecified), then I might propose that you would be better off learning Python, since it's often used in math and sciences.